# unable to obtain stable Firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium

I have windows OS
I'm trying to run Tor Browser, but i get this error
unable to obtain stable Firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Here is my code:

```
path='C:\Tor\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = path

session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)

session.visit "https://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: Can you share your firefox/selenium version? most likely you need to upgrade/downgrade them

Comment: Tor and Firefox is up to date